# Crossword algorithm for Android using Java

Tags: java, android, algorithm, crossword

I am working on cross word algorithm to develop a word app. After doing a lot of googling or search on StackOverflow, I was able to reach this point. But yet I am not able to understand the right implementation for algorithm in Java. Below is the class I used.

```
public class Crosswords {

    char[][] cross;
    int rows;
    int cols;
    char[][] numberGrid;
    boolean startword;
    final char DEFAULT = ' ';

    public Crosswords() {
        rows = 50;
        cols = 50;
        cross = new char[rows][cols];
        numberGrid = new char [rows][cols];
        for (int i = 0; i < cross.length;i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < cross[i].length;j++){
                cross[i][j] = DEFAULT;
            }
        }
    }

    public Crosswords(int ros, int colls) {
        rows = ros;
        cols = colls;
        cross = new char[rows][cols];
        numberGrid = new char [rows][cols];
        for (int i = 0;i < cross.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < cross[i].length; j++){
                cross[i][j] = DEFAULT;
            }
        }
    }


    public String toString() {
             String s = new String();
            //String d = new String();
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++){
          s = s + cross[i][j] + " ";
            }
          s = s + "\n";
        }
        return s;
    }


    public void addWordh(String s, int r, int c) {

        int i = 0;

        int j = 0;

        boolean b = true;

        boolean intersectsWord = true;


        if (s.length() > cols) {

            System.out.println(s + " is longer than the grid. Please try another word.");

            return;

        }

        if (c + s.length() > cols) {

            System.out.println(s + " is too long. Please try another word.");

            return;

        }

        if ((r - 2) >= 0) {

            if ((cross[r - 1][c - 1 + s.length()] == DEFAULT) || (cross[r - 1][c - 1 + s.length()] == '*')) {
                intersectsWord = false;
            }

            else { intersectsWord = true;}

            if (intersectsWord == true) {
                System.out.println("The word " + s + " intersects the beginning of another word!");
                return;
            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

            if ((cross[r - 1][c - 1 + i] == DEFAULT) || (cross[r - 1][c - 1 + i] == s.charAt(i))) {

                b = true;

            }

            else {

                b = false;

                System.out.println("Unable to add " + s + ". Please try another word.");

                return;}

        }

        if (b == true) {

            if ((s.length() <= cols) && (c + s.length() <= cols) &&

                    (cross[r - 1][c - 1] == s.charAt(0)) || (cross[r - 1][c - 1] == DEFAULT)) {

                while (j < s.length()) {


                    cross[r - 1][c - 1 + j] = s.charAt(j);

                    if (j==0){
                        startword = true;
                    }

                    cross[rows - 1 - (r - 1)][cols - 1 - (c - 1 + j)] = '*';

                    j++;

                }

            }

        }

    }

    public void addWordv(String s, int r, int c) {

        int i = 0;

        int j = 0;

        boolean b = true;

        boolean intersectsWord = true;

        if (s.length() > rows) {

            System.out.println(s + " is longer than the grid. Please try another word.");

        }

        if (r + s.length() > rows) {

            System.out.println(s + " is too long. Please try another word.");

        }

        else {

            if ((r - 2) >= 0) {

                if ((cross[r - 2][c - 1] == DEFAULT) || (cross[r - 2][c - 1] == '*')) {

                    intersectsWord = false;

                }

                else { intersectsWord = true;}

                if (intersectsWord == true) {

                    System.out.println("The word " + s + " intersects the end of another word!");

                    return;

                }

            }
            if ((cross[r - 1 + s.length()][c - 1] == DEFAULT) || (cross[r - 1 + s.length()][c - 1] == '*')) {
                intersectsWord = false;
            }

            else { intersectsWord = true;}

            if (intersectsWord == true) {
                System.out.println("The word " + s + " intersects the end of another word!");
                return;
            }


            for (i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

                if ((cross[r - 1 + i][c - 1] == DEFAULT) || (cross[r - 1 + i][c - 1] == s.charAt(i))) {

                    b = true;

                }

                else {

                    b = false;

                    System.out.println("Unable to add " + s + ". Please try another word.");

                    return;}

            }

            if (b == true) {

                if ((s.length() <= rows) && (r + s.length() <= cols) &&

                        (cross[r - 1][c - 1] == s.charAt(0)) || (cross[r - 1][c - 1] == DEFAULT)) {

                    while (j < s.length()) {

                        cross[r - 1 + j][c - 1] = s.charAt(j);

                        if (j==0){
                            startword = true;
                        }

                        cross[rows - 1 - (r - 1 + j)][cols - 1 - (c - 1)] = '*';

                        j++;

                    }

                }

            }
        }

    }

    public void setNumberGrid(){
        numberGrid = new char [rows][cols];
        for (int i = 0; i < cross.length; i++){
            for (int j=0; j < cross[rows].length; j++){
                if (cross[i][j] == DEFAULT){
                    numberGrid[i][j] = (char) 0;
                }
                else if (startword == true){
                    numberGrid[i][j] = (char) -2;
                }
                else {
                    numberGrid[i][j] = (char) -1;
                }
            }
            int count = 1;
            for (i=0; i < cross.length; i++){
                for (int j=0; j < cross[rows].length; j++){
                    if (numberGrid[i][j] == -2){
                        numberGrid[i][j] = (char)count;
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public String printNumberGrid() {
        for (int i=0; i < cross.length; i++){
            for (int j=0; j < cross[rows].length; j++){
                if (numberGrid[i][j] == (char)-1){
                    numberGrid[i][j] = ' ';
                }
                else if (numberGrid[i][j] == (char)0){
                    numberGrid[i][j] = '#';
                }
            }
        }
        String d = new String();
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++){
                d = d + numberGrid[i][j] + " ";
            }
            d = d + "\n";
        }
        return d;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Crosswords g = new Crosswords();
        g.addWordv("rawr", 4, 5);
        g.addWordh("bot", 5, 4);
        g.addWordv("raw", 7, 5);
        g.addWordh("cat", 4, 5);
        g.addWordh("bass", 6, 10);
        System.out.println(g);

        Crosswords c = new Crosswords(20, 20);

        c.addWordh("HELLO", 1, 1);

        c.addWordv("HAPLOID", 1, 1);
        c.addWordh("COMPUTER", 3, 12);

        c.addWordv("CAT", 2, 11);

        c.addWordv("WOAH", 2, 20);
        c.addWordh("PARKING", 20, 5);

        c.addWordv("ARK", 17, 6);
        c.addWordh("AHOY", 6, 18);
        c.addWordv("AHOY", 18, 10);
        c.addWordv("ADVANTAGE", 2, 12);
        c.addWordv("INTERNAL", 2, 18);
        c.addWordh("BANTER", 7, 11);
        c.addWordv("BEAGLE", 5, 12);
        c.addWordh("BASE", 8, 3);
        c.addWordv("BALL", 8, 3);
        c.addWordh("LEFT", 10, 3);
        c.addWordv("SAFE", 8, 5);
        System.out.print(c);
    }
}
```

As you can see in Main method that i am adding the words but also giving the row and column number to place the words like **c.addWordv("Safe",8,5);** where 8 and 5 is column number.

Now **Question** is how can i implement cross word algorithm which just take words and place them on board randomly without taking the row and column numbers.
Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**
I want to modify this class algo the way that i dont have to give away the rows and columns number..

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not understand what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Actually, I see major errors. Posting an answer

Comment: Try googling for brute force search. What you're trying to do isn't trivial, but as a start, you put some word at a location and then try put others according to the letters already on the crossword. If you fail to do so, you cancel your last selection and do it again with a different word.

Comment: @dodo okay i will look into the brute force and will do as you explain.

Comment: @Polarbear0106 I am actually trying to implement cross word algorithm in android using JAVA.

Comment: If you cannot start it on Android, what good is it?

Comment: @Polarbear0106 Sir problem is not how to start it on android actually i am simply implementing it in console first and also i am facing problem as i insert words to this algo i also need to give it the column number and row number. I want to achieve the results that i simply insert the words to the cross word algo and it can fill the board with these words checking their intersections.

Comment: ok then. Have fun when it works and you cannot start it

Comment: @Polarbear0106 i was working using your answer which i saw later you removed it??

Comment: You literally said that it was not what you were asking for

Comment: 'Sir problem is not how to start it on android'

Comment: Okay sorry sir i might not able to convey my self well but can you please post your answer again? I will be grateful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

//Pseudo Code

If the crossword size is maxSize and any word's length is stored in wordLength ,then you can use random method as below
        int maxSize=20;
        int wordLength=4;

```
    Random random =new Random();
    int r,c;
    //for horizontal
     r=random.nextInt(maxSize-wordLength);
     c=random.nextInt(maxSize);
    //for vertical
     r=random.nextInt(maxSize);
     c=random.nextInt(maxSize-wordLength);
```

You can store the row and column and generate the new one if its already present.

Comment: Thanks. It is a good way to generate random rows and columns but when i do like this there isn't even one word which is placed on grid

Comment: And whats the point if we are giving the column and row number ourselves becasue then we are also defining their intersected words too its. Wouldn't it be like hard coding the words in puzzle

Comment: Could you please explain your doubt because the nextInt method will generate random number for the given word, its length and Crossword size is used so that word does not get outside the board.